# How to VPN to Ubuntu server so I can browse the Internet?

Tags: vpn

I want to browse the internet from work by passing my traffic via an encrypted link to my home ubuntu server and out on to the internet from there. Obviously the replies will have to go to my home server first and then back to me via the encrypted link. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working?

Typical use cases are

a: watching UK only websites when i am abroad on business (so i appear to be in the UK)
b: bypassing the web filters at work which are so stupidly restrictive they block access to my personal blog which is about running and on which I am currently trying to raise sponsorship money for charity before the London marathon in a week!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a SOCKS proxy. It requires you have SSH access to the server you are using as a proxy. Change your web browser's proxy settings for `SOCKS Proxy` to `127.0.0.1`, set the `Port` to `8000`, and also check the box for `SOCKS v5`

Next, create the SSH connection and send traffic for port 8000 on your machine to the server:

`ssh -D 8000 your_ssh_username@your_remote_server`

`your_remote_server` can be the name of your server in DNS (myserver.example.com) or an IP address. Use a dynamic DNS service if your home IP address changes frequently.

Leave that SSH connection open while you surf. If you want to go back to 'regular' surfing, undo the changes you made in your web browser's proxy settings.

Verify that your web browser is using the proxy by visiting a site that shows your IP address such as www.icanhazip.com - it should show the IP address of your Ubuntu server and not the IP address of the computer you are using.

Comment: Brilliant! It just works straight out of the box. Thanks so much. The hardest bit was getting WoL working over the internet (unrelated) but that is working now and now I can browse to my hearts content. Thanks so much.